# Create Row where no value is given Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am probably just thinking about this wrong but I am trying not to redo work here.

I have a query that finds all the credit ratings of customers and creates an average with some other data.

```
DECLARE @StartDate int = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE()-90, 112)
DECLARE @EndDate int = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)

SELECT
    [Credit Rating],
    LoanTypeKey,
    LoanTypeDescription,
    MIN(InterestRate) AS Minimum_Rate,
    MIN(NULLIF(InterestRate, 0)) AS Minimum_Rate_Non_Zero,
    MAX(interestrate) AS Maximum_Rate,
    CONCAT(MIN(InterestRate), ' - ', MAX(interestrate)) AS [Given_Rates],
    CONCAT(MIN(NULLIF(InterestRate, 0)),' - ', MAX(interestrate)) AS [Given_Rates_Non_Zero],
    AVG(InterestRate) AS '90Day Avg Interest Rate'
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT        
         LoanTypeKey,
         ls.AccountNumber, ls.LoanID,
         lc.LoanTypeDescription, InterestRate,
         CASE 
             WHEN ld.LoanCreditScore >= 740 THEN 'A+'
             WHEN ld.LoanCreditScore >= 740 THEN 'A+'
             WHEN ld.LoanCreditScore >= 700 THEN 'A'
             WHEN ld.LoanCreditScore >= 670 THEN 'B'
             WHEN ld.LoanCreditScore >= 640 THEN 'C'
             WHEN ld.LoanCreditScore >= 600 THEN 'D'
             WHEN ld.LoanCreditScore >= 1 THEN 'E'
             ELSE 'No Credit Score'
         END AS 'Credit Rating'
     FROM 
         cu.LAFactLoanSnapShot ls       
     INNER JOIN 
         arcu.ARCULoanCategory lc ON ls.loantypekey = lc.LoanType
     INNER JOIN 
         [ARCUSYM000].[arcu].[ARCULoanDetailed] ld ON ls.AccountNumber = ld.AccountNumber
                                                   AND ld.ProcessDate = ls.ProcessDate
     WHERE      
         -- LoanStatus = 'Open' 
         OpenDateKey BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
         AND InterestRate != 0) x
GROUP BY
    LoanTypeKey, x.[Credit Rating], LoanTypeDescription
ORDER BY
    LoanTypeKey, [Credit Rating]
```

Now my issue here is that if there are no New Cars being sold to someone with a E credit rating in the last 90 days then there is no row for E rating with new cars. I want to be able to add that row with other values if any of the credit ratings  A+, A, B, C, D, E, 'No Credit Score') are not represented by a customer in the last 90 days.

| Credit Rating | LoanTypeKey | Loan Type Description | 90Day Average Interest rate | MinRate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 500 | New Car | 4.99 | 1.0 |
| B | 500 | New Car | 4.5 | 1.0 |
| C | 500 | New Car | 4.6 | 1.0 |
| D | 500 | New Car | 4.3 | 1.0 |
| E | 500 | New Car | 4.5 | 1.0 |
| No Credit Score | 501 | New Car | 2.1 | 1.0 |
| A | 501 | Used Car | 2.1 | 1.0 |
| B | 501 | Used Car | 2.1 | 1.0 |
| C | 501 | Used Car | 2.4 | 1.0 |
| D | 501 | Used Car | 2.5 | 1.0 |
| No Credit Score | 501 | Used Car | 4.1 | 1.0 |

This is an example of my current table with a few columns taken out.
You can see that **Used Car** does not have an **E** Credit Rating.
I just want E to be included with all other columns blank.

For example:

| Credit Rating | LoanTypeKey | Loan Type Description | 90Day Average Interest rate | MinRate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E | 501 | Used Car |  |  |

Keep in mind I have 20+ other Loan types

Comment: Start with the table that holds the loan types, and then left join from there

Comment: A LEFT JOIN comes straight to mind, I'm struggling to understand fully, wonder if you could provide example data and expected output from that data.

Comment: @GuidoG Good point! I should have a table with just those.

Comment: its kinda hard to say without the table structures. but you might want to `left join` on `ARCULoanDetailed`. though i'm not sure if those `Used Cars` with `No Credit Score` in the example table actually a "no credit" or an "E."

Comment: When they don't have any credit score I labeled them as "no Credit score'

Answer (score 0):

First, create a dummy table of [Credit Rating] letters by using WITH

```
    With letters as 
    (SELECT *
      FROM (VALUES ('A')
                 , ('B')
                 , ('C')
                 , ('D')
                 , ('E')
           ) t1 (letter))
Select letter from letters...
```

Then you can use CROSS JOIN to get missing values. This is the link to the answer that I found which also helped me to solve similar query couple months back.

[T-SQL Cross Join to get missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163312/t-sql-cross-join-to-get-missing-values).

LEFT JOIN won't solve the issue

Comment: It's not a "`WITH`"; the above is a Common Table Expression (CTE). `WITH` is a keyword that can appear in many places: `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`, `FROM {Table Name} WITH ({Query Hint})`, `CREATE TABLE ... WITH ({Table Options})` to name a few.

Comment: No, you *do* want a `LEFT JOIN` (with `letters` on the left/first), because a `CROSS JOIN` will just get all combinations multiplied by available combinations

Comment: @Charlieface please follow the link above, it will explain how the CROSS JOIN trick worked in this case.

Comment: No that answer left-joins afterwards. The cross-join was just to generate all possible combinations first (instead of using `values` like you)